# PHP; OOP Class variable

Tags: php, class, oop, sqlsrv

class.sqlsrv.php

```
class SQLSRV {

    var $SERVERNAME   = _SERVERNAME_;
    var $DATABASENAME = _DATABASENAME_;
    var $USERNAME     = _USERNAME_;
    var $PASSWORD     = _PASSWORD_;
    var $CONNECTED;
    var $DATABASESTATE;

    function __construct()
    {
        # code...
    }

    function connect()
    {
        $CONNECTIONINFO     = array(
                                    'Database'                  => $this->DATABASENAME,
                                    'UID'                       => $this->USERNAME,
                                    'PWD'                       => $this->PASSWORD,
                                    "MultipleActiveResultSets"  => true,
                                    "CharacterSet"              => 'UTF-8'
                              );
        $this->CONNECTED = sqlsrv_connect( $this->SERVERNAME, $CONNECTIONINFO) or $this->_error();
    }
}
```

mainfile.php

```
require_once('includes/class/class.sqlsrv.in.php');
$db = new SQLSRV();
```

index.php

```
require_once('content.php');
```

content.php

```
<?php
   $res['sectionlist'] = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Section");
   while ($arr['sectionlist'] = $db->fetch($res['sectionlist'])) {
?>
<tr>
   <td>
      <?php echo $arr['sectionlist']['Name'];?>
   </td>
   <td>
      <span class="label label-default"> pending </span>
   </td>
   <td>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs default blue-stripe"> detail </a>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs default red-stripe"> delete </a>
   </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

but when I run this code it shows errors

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\MA\plugins\admin\content.php on line 2

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\MA\plugins\admin\content.php on line 2
```

It works if I call `$db = new SQLSRV();` before `$res['sectionlist'] = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Section");`

Comment: Where are you including or requiring `mainfile.php`?

Comment: index.php -> included mainfile.php then mainfile.php included class.sqlsrv.php     index.php - included conent.php for show content

Comment: edit your question to show that then.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't import the `mainfile.php` file where you initiliaze the `$db` variable before using it in `content.php`.

Either import it in `index.php` like that:

```
require_once('mainfile.php');
require_once('content.php');
```

Or import it in `content.php` like that:

```
<?php
   require_once('mainfile.php');
   $res['sectionlist'] = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Section");
   while ($arr['sectionlist'] = $db->fetch($res['sectionlist'])) {
?>
```

Of course, you have to set the correct path in the `require_once()` statement. `require_once('mainfile.php');` will look for `mainfile.php` in the same directory of the php script that calls it. See php's [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) documentation for more details.